# Is it possible to create Site Collection such that URL should not have "/sites" in SharePoint foundation 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, site-collection

I want to create Site Collection such that Site collection should not contain "/sites" in its URL(Except root Site Collection) in SharePoint Foundation 2010.
Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that you could look at the managed paths

1. Open Sharepoint Central Administration -> Application Managment -> Manage web applications
2. Select your web application
3. Click Managed Paths button on the ribbon

You will see that there are at least two path:

- Root (Explicit inclusion)
- sites (Wildcard inclusion)

Explicit inclusion means that you can create only one site collection with this path. Wildcard inclusion means that you can create so many sites as you wish.

if you would not want to use \sites, you can add you own path. After this you can select this path on site collection creation page.

Comment: Please make sure you implement a 'root' site collection as this will leave you unsupported if you don't. Without a root site collection many things break, like InfoPath, Workflows, Visio services as these all expect the root site collection to exist.